# ld: library not found for -lxml2 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: objective-c, clang, libxml2, exit-code

I am using libxml2 framework in my application.

But it is showing this error:

ld: library not found for -lxml2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I also changed the header search path to -  /usr/include/libxml2

Here is the build output:

```
Ld /Users/classic/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeleSketchProj-aiaovvbknclizsekxxhxxqthzauf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TeleSketchProj.app/TeleSketchProj normal armv7
cd /Users/classic/Desktop/TeleSketchProj
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -L/Users/classic/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeleSketchProj-aiaovvbknclizsekxxhxxqthzauf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/classic/Desktop/TeleSketchProj/Twitter+OAuth/SAOAuthTwitterEngine -F/Users/classic/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeleSketchProj-aiaovvbknclizsekxxhxxqthzauf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/classic/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeleSketchProj-aiaovvbknclizsekxxhxxqthzauf/Build/Intermediates/TeleSketchProj.build/Debug-iphoneos/TeleSketchProj.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TeleSketchProj.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -lz -lxml2 -framework CFNetwork -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AVFoundation -framework AddressBookUI -framework AddressBook -framework MediaPlayer -framework AudioToolbox -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreAudio -framework Security -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lOAuth -framework SenTestingKit -o /Users/classic/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeleSketchProj-aiaovvbknclizsekxxhxxqthzauf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TeleSketchProj.app/TeleSketchProj
```

Please suggest something..

Thanks!

Comment: Post the build output (specifically the linker invocation line) with your question.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check

Comment: You didn't provided `ld` with the path to `libxml2.a` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with typing -ObjC in other linker flags in build setting of your app.It may work...

Comment: NO, it didn't work for me.. FYI it is working fine with simulator but the error comes up for device.